# yii2 append data through renderAjax missing in post data

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, append

I have two model A and B , In Model A form append Model B from dynamically,but when am click create button ,I am not getting model B data in POST.where I am doing wrong please help..

Model A  Form(view)

```
       <?php
        use yii\helpers\Html;
        use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
        use yii\helpers\Url;
        use yii\web\View;
        $script = <<< JS

        $.ajax({
        type     :'POST',            
        data: {total_form:1},
        cache    : true,
        url  : '/stag_str/web/index.php/activities/create',
        success  : function(data) {
        $('.p_scents').append(data);
        },
        });

        JS;
        $this->registerJs($script);
        ?>

        <div class="currency-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'currency_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'style'=>'width:150px']) ?>
        <div class="p_scents"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

        </div>
```

Model A controller

```
      public function actionCreate(){
        $model = new Currency();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        print_r($_POST);exit;
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->currency_id]);
        } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        ]);
        }
      }
```

Model B Form which  I am rendering through Ajax call

```
            <?php

        use yii\helpers\Html;
        use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

        /* @var $this yii\web\View */
        /* @var $model app\models\Activities */
        /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
        ?>

        <div class="activities-form">

         <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'activity' ]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'activity_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

        </div>
```

Model B action using renderAjax

```
            public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new Activities();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->activity_id]);
        } elseif ( Yii::$app->request->isAjax ){
           return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
                'model' => $model,
           ]);
        }

        }
```

I am not getting Model B form data while saving Model form A..

Comment: update you question adding related  models, controller/action  and view code ..

Comment: can you please cross-check the request if it is Ajax call using print_r(Yii::$app->request->isAjax); exit();   You must get true.

Comment: put this code in actionsCreate() for Model B.

Comment: Also can you please add id to your form like, $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => 'activity-form' ]);

Comment: Hi Ankur thanks for reply. updated but not working , still same problem

Comment: Still am not getting Model B form data in POST

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, when you are dealing with AJAX Calls from View. you Must provide an ID to your form as below;

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => 'activity-form' ]);
```

when you handle any kind of request inside the Controllers, you must first check the type of request when you re-render your form as below

```
elseif ( Yii::$app->request->isAjax ){
   return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankur, still it's not working , am tried but again facing same issue.

Comment: What do you get in print_r(Yii::$app->request->isAjax);

Comment: Model A form data also missed.

Comment: I am not getting anything when am using print_r(Yii::$app->request->isAjax);